# Is it acceptable to use variable != null instead of variable !== undefined && variable !== null?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that where a variable could be `undefined`, `null`, or a normal value.  The code needs to do the same thing regardless of whether the variable is `undefined` or `null`.  Is there a danger to saying

```
for (var cur = this.buckets[i]; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {
```

instead of

```
for (var cur = this.buckets[i]; cur !== undefined && cur !== null; cur = cur.next) {
```

The full program is below (the line in question is in `HashTable.prototype.walk`).

```
var hash_seed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

function jenkins_hash(key, interval_size) {
    var hash = hash_seed;
    for (var i=0; i<key.length; ++i) {
        hash += key.charCodeAt(i);
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    // make unsigned and modulo interval_size
    return (hash >>> 0) % interval_size;
}

//constructor, takes the number of buckets to create
function HashTable(size) {
    this.buckets = new Array(size);
}

//private method, ignore
HashTable.prototype._position = function(key) {
    var index = jenkins_hash(key, this.buckets.length);
    var cur   = this.buckets[index];

    if (cur === undefined) {  
          return { i: index, cur: null, prev: null };
    }

    var prev = cur;
    for (; cur !== null; cur = cur.next) {
        if (cur.key == key) {
            return { i: index, cur: cur, prev: prev };
        }
        prev = cur;
    }

    return { i: index, cur: cur, prev: prev };
};

// associate a value with a key in the hash
HashTable.prototype.store = function(key, value) {
    var r = this._position(key);
    if (r.prev === null) {  
          this.buckets[r.i] = {
              key: key, value: value, next: null  
          };
          return;
    }

    if (r.cur !== null) {
        r.cur.value = value;
        return;
    }

    r.prev.next = {
        key: key, value: value, next: null  
    };
    return;
};

// fetches the value associated with the key
// returns undefined if the key is not in the hash
HashTable.prototype.fetch = function(key) {
    var r = this._position(key);
    if (r.cur === null) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return r.cur.value;
};

// returns true if the key is in the hash
// returns false if the key isn't in the hash
HashTable.prototype.exists = function(key) {
    var r = this._position(key);
    return r.cur !== null;
};

// removes a key from the hash
HashTable.prototype.delete = function(key) {
    var r = this._position(key);
    if (r.cur === null) {
        return;  
    }
    if (r.cur === r.prev) {
        this.buckets[r.i] = r.cur.next;  
    }
    r.prev.next = r.cur.next;
};

// removes all keys from the hash
HashTable.prototype.clear = function() {
    var length   = this.buckets.length;
    this.buckets = new Array(length);
};

// run a funciton for every key/value pair in the hash
// function signature should be function(k, v) {}
// WARNING: adding keys to the hash while this method is
// running may lead to unexpected results
HashTable.prototype.walk = function(func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.buckets.length; i++) {
        for (var cur = this.buckets[i]; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {
            func(cur.key, cur.value);
        }  
    }  
};

// returns all of the keys in the hash
HashTable.prototype.keys = function() {
    var keys = [];
    this.walk(function(k,v) { keys.push(k) });
    return keys;
};

// run a function for every key/value pair in the hash
// function signature should be function(k, v) {}
// WARNING: only keys in the hash when the method is called
// will be visited; however, changes to their values will be
// reflected
HashTable.prototype.safer_walk = function(func) {
    var keys = this.keys();
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        func(keys[i], this.fetch(keys[i]));
    }
}

var h = new HashTable(101);

h.store("abc", 5);
h.store("def", 6);
h.walk(function(k, v) { console.log(k + " => " + v) });
```

Comment: Simply place a comment that comparison using the `!=` operator was correct - that would be sufficient in my opinion.  Having said that though, I'm not sure this is really something for SO to answer.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy If I have to add a comment to make it clear to other programmers, then I should probably just change it to the latter.

Comment: It's not that it's not clear (as Pointy said, the algorithm is in the specification) - it's that they might believe that you were intending to only compare to null, not undefined and null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semantics of `!=` are well-defined.  If you compare to `null`, then:

- if "cur" is `undefined` or `null`, then the result is `false`
- if "cur" is anything else, then the result is `true`

The "abstract" equality comparison (like the strict comparison) first checks the type of each operand (which, note well, is different from what `typeof` returns!).  The type of `null` is the Null type, and the type of `undefined` is the Undefined type.  The abstract comparison algorithm explicitly considers `undefined` and `null` to be equal.

Thus there's really no point doing your own explicit check for both `null` and `undefined`. (You may want to check separately of course if you need logic that's *different* from the abstract comparison built into the language.)

Comment: boy did I confuse myself trying to summarize `===` for this :-)

Comment: If I am reading what you wrote correctly, then there is no danger: the two statements are functionally identical (and I can ignore the warning my editor is throwing).

Comment: @Chas.Owens yes I just added a little more stuff. [The spec is here.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)